# C++ Program has Stop Working LINK LIST

Tags: c++, data-structures, codeblocks

The following code is working fine for 3 4 or some time 6 inputs and then comes up with "program has stop working" i have checked every thing but didn't get a clue Im using code-blocks.

```
struct info{
string name;
string phone;
};

struct node{
info contact;
node *link;
};

void SaveToFile(node *start);
void AddNode(node *&start, info contact);
void display(node *start);

int main()
{

bool check = true;
int choice;
info Newcontact;
node *start = NULL;

    while(check){
        cout<<" ----------------------------- \n";
        cout<<"|       PHONE DIRECTORY       |\n";
        cout<<" ----------------------------- \n";
        cout<<"|1: Insert a Contact          |\n";
        cout<<"|4: DISPlAY Contacts          |\n";
        cout<<"|6: EXIT                      |\n";
        cout<<" ----------------------------- \n";

        cout<<"Enter your choice: ";
        cin>>choice;

        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            cout<<"Enter Name: ";
            cin>>Newcontact.name;
            cout<<"Enter Contact No: ";
            cin>>Newcontact.phone;
            AddNode(start,Newcontact);
            break;

        case 4:
            display(start);
            break;

        case 6:
            check = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

These are my functions of adding new element and displaying link list

```
void AddNode(node *&start, info User_contact){
node *temp, *p;
p=start;
temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
temp->contact = User_contact;

if(start==NULL){
    start = temp;
    temp ->link=NULL;
}
else{
    while(p->link!=NULL){
        p=p->link;
    }

      p->link=temp;
      temp->link=NULL;
}
}

void display(node *start){
node *p = start;
while(p!=NULL){
    cout<<"NAME: "<<p->contact.name<<"  "<<"PNONE: "<<p->contact.phone<<"\n";
    p=p->link;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, short answer: if you are writing C++ code, don't use `malloc`, `calloc` and other *alloc. You have nice `new` and `delete`. With *alloc you don't get enougth memory for `std::string`, because `std::string` is class too and you have to allocate memory for each string as well.